# datepicker display two different kind of calendar

Tags: jquery, calendar, datepicker

Good day,

In one page, I want to display two different kind of calendar. One is displaying the months and years only which is already done. And the other one is showing the full calendar. But my problem is this.

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
        display: none;
}
```

I think both my calendar is sharing the same class. What should I do to show the full calendar on my second datepicker?

EDITED

Here's What I did.

```
<style>
#datepicker1.ui-datepicker-calendar {
  display: block;
}
#datepicker2.ui-datepicker-calendar {
  display: none;
}
</style>

<input id="datepicker1" />
<input id="datepicker2" />

<script>
$("#datepicker1").datepicker();
$("#datepicker2").datepicker();
</script>
```

I know something is wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

EDITED

Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/m55vn/

Comment: create a css rule based on class or id of the one you want to show and make it more specific than rule shown  `#fullCalendar.ui-datepicker-calendar{ display:block}`

Comment: Can you provide example? I don't think I get it right.

Comment: ok..sorry...need to wrap `datepicker1` in parent element and use that for css. `datapicker` calendar  is a sibling of the input. WHen in doubt inspect elements in live html view within your browser console

Comment: wrap datepicker1? How? Can you please provide clear example? Can you post it in the answers section so I can mark it the correct answer. Thanks again.

Comment: create a demo in jsfiddle.net, will adjust there

Comment: Added a link to the jsfiddle.